# Field returning 0 while IDE debug shows it at the proper initialised value

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm using reflection to create instances of all classes derived from ItemPart as follows:

```
        //Create UI from reflection
    private void DisplayParts(string partGroup)
    {
        List<ItemPart> validParts = GetPartsList(partGroup);
        foreach(ItemPart part in validParts)
        {
            GameObject obj = Instantiate(UIController.ObjectPrefabs[UIController.ObjectPrefabsEnum.ButtonDescription], UI_PartsList.transform);
            DescriptionButton button = obj.GetComponent<DescriptionButton>();
            button.Title.text = part.PartName;
            button.Description.text = part.Description;
            button.ActivateAction = delegate { DesignBench.CreatePart(part); };
        }
    }
    
    //Get classes derived from ItemPart and return a list of instances
    private List<ItemPart> GetPartsList(string partGroup)
    {
        List<Type> types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes()).Where(p => typeof(ItemPart).IsAssignableFrom(p) && p != typeof(ItemPart) ).ToList();

        List<ItemPart> validParts = new List<ItemPart>();

        foreach(Type type in types)
        {
            ItemPart part = (ItemPart)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            if (part.PartGroup == partGroup)
            {
                validParts.Add(part);
            }
        }
        return validParts;
    }
```

After accessing variables in this class, I've found while the IDE is claiming they are correctly at their initialised values, they are reading by the program as being 0:

```
public class Handle : ItemPart 
{
//...
        public new PartModifiableStats ModifiableStats = new PartModifiableStats()
        {
            SizeX = new ModifiableStat<float>() { IsEnabled = false, Value = 5 },
            SizeY = new ModifiableStat<float>() { IsEnabled = true, Value = 20, Bounds = new Vector2(10, 150) },
            Material = new ModifiableStat<Materials.Material>() { IsEnabled = true, Value = Materials.MaterialDict[Materials.MaterialTypes.Iron] }
        };
//...
}
```

https://puu.sh/GcS8h/9a3c26de2b.png
https://puu.sh/GcS8L/4911fbd3d8.png

Supposedly, Activator.CreateInstance(type) uses the type's empty constructor, which if I'm not mistaken, should also properly initialise all the variables in the type it is creating. Why is this value still reading as zero, and why is there a discrepency between what the program is reading and what the IDE believes the value to be?

```
        public struct ModifiableStat<T>
        {
            public bool IsEnabled;
            public T Value;
            public Vector2 Bounds;
        }
        public struct PartModifiableStats
        {
            public ModifiableStat<float> SizeX;
            public ModifiableStat<float> SizeY;
            public ModifiableStat<Materials.Material> Material;
        }
```

Comment: Can you show the code of the propert `SizeX`? (getter/setter)  (forgot to assign the field?)

Comment: "*should also properly initialise all the variables in the type it is creating*" how is it initializing them (what values), and what do you expect to happen, and why do you expect that? Do you have anything in the default constructor, or are they auto fields/initialized properties ?

Comment: The thing that look strange is this public field which is marked with `new`. You should use virtual properties instead. If you want to assign the `ModifiableStats` field on creation, you should assign it in the parameterless constructor.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen - I was using abstract properties, but as a property returns a copy of a value type, you can't directly edit its member fields/properties. It's probably a poor solution, but simply overriding a field struct allowed both direct access to the members and allowed me to give it initial values on creation.

I did not use the parameterless constructor as I thought it was messy to assign the initial values for the entire class there. Please inform me if that is naive.

I could of course change the PartModifiableStats object to a class, and then make it an abstract property.

Comment: @TheGeneral The parameterless constructor is the default implicit constructor for the class. The values are initialised as shown above, not in the constructor. The class will never be initialised with values other than the above, so I thought it pointless to put it in a constructor. As I said above, that may be naive.

Comment: @CalvinSoueid ok that sums up a few things, however, they initialize as per normal for me. https://dotnetfiddle.net/aPol12 What values are you expecting ?

Comment: @TheGeneral https://dotnetfiddle.net/Xw5Dud

This is the actual architecture. Handle inherits from ItemPart, overrides ModifiableStats to initialise the values, and is then created and cast to ItemPart.

This for some reason uses the initial values of ItemPart rather than its derivative Handle.

It seems to use the initial values of the type it's *cast* to, not the type it actually is, which doesn't seem correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you have not *overriding* `PartModifiableStats`, you are making a new property/field in the child class. Both values get initialized and they can be accessed via a *cast*.

Take this nonsensical example to see exactly what is happening

```
public class Parent
{
   public int Value { get; set; }= 10;
}

public class Child : Parent
{
   public  int Value { get; set; } = 20;
}

...

var part = new Child();

Console.WriteLine("Child Value = " + part.Value);
Console.WriteLine("Parent Value = " + ((Parent)part).Value);

((Parent)part).Value = 25;
  
Console.WriteLine("Child Value = " + part.Value);
Console.WriteLine("Parent Value = " + ((Parent)part).Value);
```

**Output**

```
Child Value = 20
Parent Value = 10
Child Value = 20
Parent Value = 25
```

What you are likely after is something more like this. Where the value is overridden and the same value persists with the cast

```
public class Parent
{
   public virtual int Value { get; set; }= 10;
}

public class Child : Parent
{
   public override int Value { get; set; } = 20;
}
```

**Output**

```
Child Value = 20
Parent Value = 20
Child Value = 25
Parent Value = 25
```